# How can I return or load a specific date?

Tags: php, url, date

Is there a way to return or load the calendar by an get URL. Something like calendar.php?gotoDate=2010-10-21 ?

Many Thanks!

**Edits go here (not in answers or comments):**

Oops! I'm sorry: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: Could you elaborate? What calendar are you talking about? My crystal ball is in the shop for a tune-up, sorry

Comment: Come on Edwin. Don't be shy. Add some details.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but you need to code it yourself. The calendar is a jquery plugin. You will need to read the query string, and set the calendar date to whatever is there in javascript.

Why do you need to set it by url?